# Elasticsearch to Spark Streaming

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I'm analyzing logs and I have this architecture:

kafka->spark streaming -> elastic search

My main goal is to create machine learning models in streaming. I think that I can do two things:

1) Kafka->spark Streaming (ML) -> elastic search

2) Kafka->spark Streaming-> elasticsearch -> spark streaming(ML)

-I think that the second architecture is the best since spark streaming will use indexed data directely. What do you think? is that correct? 
-Can we easly connecte spark streaming to elasticsearch in real time?
-If we create a model in spark streaming (after elastic search) must we use this model in this place (after elasticsearch) or we can use it in spark streaming (directery after kafka) ? #use== predict in real time
-Does creating models after elasticsearch made our models static (or not in the real time approch)

Thank you.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not `real-time` system. __Source__: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html#_near_realtime_nrt

Comment: In the documentation, they said that it takes 1 second to become searchable, so do you think it's the same to be transformed to spark streaming? Else, you think  Kafka->spark Streaming (ML) -> elastic search is better?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Anything beyond `1 second` is not real-time anymore. If you want your application to be `real-time` then elasticsearch may not serve that no matter where(after spark streaming or before) you put into it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that?

kafka -> spark Streaming -> elasticsearch db

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

//kafka group
val group_id = "receiveScanner"
// kafka topic
val topic = Map("testStreaming"-> 1)
// zk connect
val zkParams = Map(
  "zookeeper.connect" ->"localhost",
  "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000",
  "group.id" -> group_id)

// Kafka
val kafkaConsumer = KafkaUtils.createStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc,zkParams,topic,StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
val receiveData = kafkaConsumer.map(_._2 )
// printer kafka data
receiveData.print()
receiveData.foreachRDD{ rdd=>
  val transform = rdd.map{ line =>
    val data = Json.parse(line)
    // play json parse
    val id = (data \ "id").asOpt[Int] match { case Some(x) => x; case None => 0}
    val name = ( data \ "name"  ).asOpt[String] match { case Some(x)=> x ; case None => "" }
    val age = (data \ "age").asOpt[Int] match { case Some(x) => x; case None => 0}
    val address = ( data \ "address"  ).asOpt[String] match { case Some(x)=> x ; case None => "" }
    Row(id,name,age,address)
  }

  val transfromrecive = sqlContext.createDataFrame(transform,schameType)
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
  //filter age < 20 , to ES database
  transfromrecive.where(col("age").<(20)).orderBy(col("age").asc)
    .saveToEs("member/user",Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))
}

}
```

/**
    * dataframe schame
    * */

```
def schameType =  StructType(
  StructField("id",IntegerType,false)::
  StructField("name",StringType,false)::
  StructField("age",IntegerType,false)::
  StructField("address",StringType,false)::
  Nil
)
```